# i got this error and cant resolve it: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String;

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

i kown that is sunday but i got this problem, and i dont have any idea about how i fix it.
 ps: the other questions in stackoverflow are in java, im using kotlin, and are about map error, not list.

my class User

```
   @Parcelize
    class User (val primeiroLogin:Boolean, val tutorialComplete:Boolean, val 
    username:String, val uid:String, val viewed:ArrayList<String>) : Parcelable {
        constructor() : this(true,false,"","", ArrayList())
    }
```

most part of the activity where i got the error

```
var viewed = ArrayList<String>()

        private fun selectCategories(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                var cUid = ""
                val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                user?.let {
                    val uid = user.uid
                    cUid = uid
                }
                p0.children.forEach{
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                        if(user?.uid == cUid){
                            viewed = user.viewed
                        }
                }

            }

        })

    }

    private fun fetchCategories(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/categories")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
                p0.children.forEach{
                    val category = it.getValue(Category::class.java)
                    if(category != null){
                        for (i in 0..viewed.size) {
                            if(category.real_name != viewed[i]){
                                adapter.add(categories(category))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->

                    val categories = item as categories
                    val intent = Intent(view.context, LearningFirstLibras::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_KEY, categories.category)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                new_words_categories.adapter = adapter
            }

        })
```

.....
thank you guys!

Comment: already tried to:  viewed.add(user.viewed.toString()) instead of viewed = user.viewed

Comment: the viewed tab in firebase is like
Viewed: " 0: 'sports_1', 1: 'teste' "

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of the error? - Also, I think this might to turn out to be about what your database structure is.  Have you put a debugger on this and stepped through your code line by line to see what is happening?  That's how most of us figure this stuff out.

Comment: the error is solved when i use string instead of arraylist in user class val viewed.

Comment: but with this, i got all the fields in one string, i need to separate tem i got this: ['sports_1','teste']

Comment: i need help to figure out how i can separate this, or get into a array. ps: as i know firebase doenst recognize arrays when u put data in there